# Filling missing data in df.loc filtered conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I have following problem with filling nan in a filtered df.
Let's take this df :

```
   condition  value
 0     A       1
 1     B       8
 2     B     np.nan
 3     A     np.nan
 4     C       3
 5     C     np.nan
 6     A       2
 7     B       5
 8     C       4
 9     A     np.nan
10     B     np.nan
11     C     np.nan
```

How can I fill np.nan with the value from the last value based on condition, so that I get following result?

```
       condition  value
 0     A       1
 1     B       8
 2     B       8
 3     A       1
 4     C       3
 5     C       3
 6     A       2
 7     B       5
 8     C       4
 9     A       2
10     B       5
11     C       4
```

I've failed with following code (ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key):

```
conditions = set(df['condition'].tolist())

        for c in conditions :

            filter = df.loc[df['condition'] == c]

            df.loc[filter, 'value'] = df.loc[filter, 'value'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

THX & BR from Vienna

Comment: how would it work if I have more columns and only want to fill np.nan in one column?

Comment: `df['column_to_fill']=df.groupby('condition')['column_to_fill'].ffill()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your values are actual `NaN`, you simply need to do a `groupby` on `condition`, and then call `ffill` (which is essentially a wrapper for `fillna(method='ffill')`):

```
df.groupby('condition').ffill()
```

Which returns:

```
   condition value
0          A     1
1          B     8
2          B     8
3          A     1
4          C     3
5          C     3
6          A     2
7          B     5
8          C     4
9          A     2
10         B     5
11         C     4
```

If your values are strings that say `np.nan`, as in your example, then replace them before:

```
df.replace('np.nan', np.nan, inplace=True)

df.groupby('condition').ffill()
```